# For my bread crumbs anchor links are not present in magento 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, coding-style, magento-1.9

Please have a look at the code of `breadcrumbs.phtml`:

```
    <?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
    <!-- SLIDER START HERE-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="innerSlider relative">
        <div class="innerSlidercontent">
          <h2>“People with thyroid problems avoid eating millet on a daily basis 
      as it is believed to contain some”</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="insideSlidePic"> <img src="<?php echo $this-
       >  getSkinUrl('images/barnyard_millet_bisi_belle_bhaat_recipe.jpg'); ?>"  
      alt=""> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <ul class="routeMenu">
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): 

               if($_crumbInfo['title']=="Home"){
                $_crumbInfo['link']=Mage::getUrl();
            }


            ?>
                <a class="sc_hover" href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" 
    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo 
   $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
      </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <!-- SLIDER END HERE-->
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Help me to figure out why anchor links are not present in my bread crumb but the text is coming. Here I see the code some different than others bread crumbs is that code right.

Comment: In class tag relative is present there some problem occuring because of that crumbs links are not enabling any solution apreciated

Answer (score 0):

//Either replace below code and check or replace file with base file.

```
 <?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
    <!-- SLIDER START HERE-->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="innerSlider relative">

        <div class="innerSlidercontent">
          <h2>“People with thyroid problems avoid eating millet on a daily basis 
      as it is believed to contain some”</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="insideSlidePic"> <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/barnyard_millet_bisi_belle_bhaat_recipe.jpg'); ?>"  
      alt=""> </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <ul class="routeMenu">
        <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
            <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): 

               if($_crumbInfo['title']=="Home"){
                $_crumbInfo['link']=Mage::getUrl();
            }
            ?>
                <a class="sc_hover" href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" 
    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo 
   $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
            <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
                <span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
      </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDER END HERE-->
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Alternate solution copy base file to your custon design path are as follow.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

copy from base to your custom design path.

app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

Comment: thank you  for the help  but it didn't work link is not enabling

Comment: Because your code include unnecessary div tags, so I have removed and edited my above answer. please check and verify now it's working my side.

Comment: it is working without the div tags thank you but with that description also it has to come i cann't remove that description any sugestions from your side will be appreciated

Comment: As per your above comment i have again edited my answer above please copy your code from my answer and check.

Comment: In class tag relative is present there some problem occuring because of that crumbs links are not enabling any solution apreciated and very thank full

Comment: what u have changed that closing div tag has no start div tag

Answer (score 0):

Please check with default magento theme.I think breadcrumb will work. If breadcrumb is working your default theme then check your current custom theme by renaming your layout and theme files.